# Extract data in Python between two matched items from a file

Tags: python, regex, loops, csv, string-matching

```
Table 1 Qualitative composition of SERQUEL 25 mg tablets 
Ingredient  Function    Reference to standards
Tablet core     
Quetiapine fumarate Drug substance  This document
Povidone    Binder  USP
Dibasic calcium phosphate dihydrate Diluent USP
Microcrystalline cellulose  Diluent USNF
Sodium starch glycolate Disintegrant    USNF
Lactose monohydrate Diluent USNF
Magnesium stearate  Lubricant   USNF
Purified water  Granulating vehicle USP
```

The above represents sample data from a .txt file:

I have a list of substance name which I want to match against.(Example of substances from the csv file are `'Quetiapine fumarate', 'Povidone', 'Magnesium stearate'  etc etc.)` 
I have them present in a csv file. 
I want to iterate each line of my text file and create groups from one substance to another.
Example output:

```
['Quetiapine fumarate   Drug substance  This document'],
['Povidone  Binder  USP'],
['Lactose monohydrate   Diluent USNF'],
['Magnesium stearate    Lubricant   USNF']
```

given that 'Quetiapine fumarate', 'Povidone', 'Lactose monohydrate', 'Magnesium stearate' are present in my csv list of substances.

How can I do this in Python

Answer (score 0):

you can use the readlines command

`file = open(FOLDER_NAME + '/' + name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    data = file.readlines()
        for line in data:
             words=line.split()
             print(words)`

you can search for 'read from the file in python'

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp